# Cannot resolve dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, dependencies

I have to make a university project and to do that I have to clone Bookkeeper from github to create some test cases. My problem is that when I import the project with maven it shows me the error:

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.distributedlog:distributedlog-core:pom:4.11.0-SNAPSHOT in apache.snapshots (https://repository.apache.org/snapshots)
```

I have searched on internet for a solution but nothing solved my problem, I have also tried on another system and the problem persists. How can I solve this? Thank you!

P.S I am using IntelliJ

Comment: Have you tried "mvn clean install" in the console?

Comment: yes but didn't solved it, I have also tried it on a system of one of my friend and seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using snapshot version of the library? Snapshot versions should not be used (and are not intended as released version by any project). Please use below dependency  instead of snapshot.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.distributedlog</groupId>
<artifactId>distributedlog-core</artifactId>
<version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also use the latest version. Please refer the below maven repo site.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.distributedlog/distributedlog-core

Comment: because it is not my project, I have only cloned from github and tried to build with maven

Comment: Ok, but as is said, no community(company) release the snapshot version for the use. May be it could be an initial version they had just released for trial and later they have removed it. So as i mentioned, just use version 4.11.0 instead of 4.11.0-SNAPSHOT in your pom.xml and check. I am sure it would work.